# Cant setup iredmail behind existing jwilder-nginx-proxy ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, jwilder-nginx-proxy, iredmail, letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

This is my first time to setup iredmail.
Am very happy to find this Group and really hope I will get some useful answers.

Has someone here ever succeed to setup `iredmail/mariadb:stable` behind an existing `nginx jwilder/docker-gen` reverse proxy already running multiples webapp and manages `letsencrypt` certificates?

I cant get my setup to work properly.
I have to deal with `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS 301 Moved Permanently` when I try to connect to my `mail.domain.com`
I have already spent lot of time on this without a solution.
Any idea to fix this?

`iredmail-docker.conf` conf file

```
HOSTNAME=webmail.domain.com
FIRST_MAIL_DOMAIN=domain.com
FIRST_MAIL_DOMAIN_ADMIN_PASSWORD=myp@ssw0rd
MLMMJADMIN_API_TOKEN=$(openssl rand -base64 32)
ROUNDCUBE_DES_KEY=$(openssl rand -base64 24)
```

`docker-compose.yml` conf file

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  iredmail:
    container_name: iredmail
    image: iredmail/mariadb:stable
    hostname: webmail.domain.com
    environment:
      # NGINX-PROXY ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES: UPDATE ME
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=webmail.domain.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=webmail.domain.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=admin@domain.com
      # END NGINX-PROXY ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
      
    ports:
      # change the host ports to any available ports on your system, for example 8080 and 8443
      - "10080:80"
      - "10443:443"
      # keep the other ports unchanged
      - "110:110"
      - "995:995"
      - "143:143"
      - "993:993"
      - "25:25"
      - "465:465"
      - "587:587"
    volumes:
      - ./data/backup-mysql:/var/vmail/backup/mysql
      - ./data/mailboxes:/var/vmail/vmail1
      - ./data/mlmmj:/var/vmail/mlmmj
      - ./data/mlmmj-archive:/var/vmail/mlmmj-archive
      - ./data/imapsieve_copy:/var/vmail/imapsieve_copy
      - ./data/custom:/opt/iredmail/custom
      - ./data/ssl:/opt/iredmail/ssl
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./data/clamav:/var/lib/clamav
      - ./data/sa_rules:/var/lib/spamassassin
      - ./data/postfix_queue:/var/spool/postfix

    env_file:
      - iredmail-docker.conf
    networks:
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a working just solution after posting this question.

So I have a new container that will handle SSL for `webmail.domain.com` which will then proxy all requests to the the iredmail container on port 443. Find new conf files below.

Please make sure to update the network directive of your conf files to match your docker setup.

1. `iredmail docker-compose.yml` conf file

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  iredmail:
    container_name: iredmail
    image: iredmail/mariadb:stable
    hostname: webmail.domain.com
      
    ports:
      # change the host ports to any available ports on your system, for example 8080 and 8443
      - "10080:80"
      - "10443:443"
      # keep the other ports unchanged
      - "110:110"
      - "995:995"
      - "143:143"
      - "993:993"
      - "25:25"
      - "465:465"
      - "587:587"
    volumes:
      - ./data/backup-mysql:/var/vmail/backup/mysql
      - ./data/mailboxes:/var/vmail/vmail1
      - ./data/mlmmj:/var/vmail/mlmmj
      - ./data/mlmmj-archive:/var/vmail/mlmmj-archive
      - ./data/imapsieve_copy:/var/vmail/imapsieve_copy
      - ./data/custom:/opt/iredmail/custom
      - ./data/ssl:/opt/iredmail/ssl
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./data/clamav:/var/lib/clamav
      - ./data/sa_rules:/var/lib/spamassassin
      - ./data/postfix_queue:/var/spool/postfix
 
    env_file:
      - iredmail-docker.conf
    networks:
    ...
```

2. `webmail.domain.com docker-compose.yml` conf file

```
version: '3.9'

services: 
  webmail:
    container_name: webmail
    image: nginx:stable-alpine3.17
    networks:
      ...
    restart: always
    environment:
      # NGINX-PROXY ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES: UPDATE ME
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=webmail.domain.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=webmail.domain.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=postmaster@domain.com
      # END NGINX-PROXY ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
    expose:
      - 80
    volumes:
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx/
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      
networks:
   ...
```

Thats all! Run `sudo docker compose up -d` for each of your docker-compose.yml file and enjoy!!